# cygwin dlopen error: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character

Tags: c++, cygwin, shared-libraries, dlopen

This is cygwin.

I have a shared library that contains some other shared libraries, and some static libraries.   When dlopen() is called, a handle is returned, but perror() returns NULL with "Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character"

Evidently something inside my library is failing.   How can I debug this?  Is there any way to get dlopen to tell me which included library or function is at fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You check `errno` even though the function didn't fail. The value of `errno` is only defined if the previous function failed.
2. You should not be using `errno`, `perror` or `strerror` when [`dlopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html#) fails. You should be using [`dlerror`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlerror.html).

Comment: Thank you!  That's what I needed to know.